# Customize FTDI driver for custom PID and VID

Tags: serial, ftdi

I have changed PID and VID of my FTDI board for  arduino program because i wanted to rename the com port name.
The ic is  FT232R a USB to serial UART interface IC. I have store new vid and pid to EEPROM.
Now It is showing in unknown devices. I am not able to update driver of it.
I have followed this article http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=6929.0.

Can anyone tell how to make cutmoize driver for it.
Any suggestions will be very helpful.

Comment: Most likely you want to edit the .inf file to add new VID/PID options.

Comment: Thank you for a  valuable reply. I have change in inf but i am not able to install it.Would you tell me after changing inf file how to install it.

Comment: You may need to go through the convoluted "Update Driver" route in the device manager. It's not a nice method. You may need to (somehow) uninstall the old driver so that it will pick up the new one.

Comment: @Majenko Windows is saying the new driver is corrupted.

Comment: I have installed the customize driver to windows but forcefully because to driver signature issue. How to get it solve.

Answer (score 1):

**On Windows**

You can refer to FTDI's documentation [here](https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/TechnicalNotes/TN_149_Create_a_Custom_Driver_Executable.pdf) for details on how to create your own custom device driver. The FTDI website has a lot of resources for this, however they seem to be a little outdated. Microsoft details how drivers work in it's [Hardware Dev Center](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/device-installation-files).

**On Linux**

On Linux it may be as easy as registering the device with `modprobe`. For example, for a device with a VID of 0102 and a PID of 1234, execute the following from the shell:

```
modprobe ftdi_sio
echo "0102 1234" | sudo tee /sys/module/ftdi_sio/drivers/usb-serial\:ftdi_sio/new_id > /dev/null
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it, but you cannot change the PID and VID without a new certificate.

Did you changed the name with the FT-Prog Tool (MProg is outdated)?
You can download the last version from here:
https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Utilities.htm#FT_PROG

You can set everything on your FTDI chip, even change the PID and VID. But at this point, you will not be able to use the standard FTDI driver anymore as you need to sign it with a new certificate (it is about 400$/year).

What you can do is leave the PID and VID and just give another name. So you will be able to use the default driver and you will see your custom name in the device manager.

Of course, in the list you just see "USB Serial Port (COM X)". But in the description of the device (Serial port), you will find this string:
`FTDIBUS\VID_0403+PID_6011+YOURCUSTOMNAME&1\0000`

If you create an application, you can just check for this, to see if it is your module. If you want more, you have to develop and release your own driver. But you can't do it anymore without a certificate, or without start Windows in unprotected mode.